# Check if 2 strings in a wordlist are identical python

Tags: python, random

Right now I'm making a slot-machine kind of code and I've hit a roadblock.

In this piece you get a wordlist containing the outcome. (SlotOption is a different wordlist)

```
slots = [random.choice(slotOption), random.choice(slotOption), random.choice(slotOption)]
```

And I'm trying to make a piece that compare all the strings in the wordlist to check if any of them are the same. Can someone help?

Comment: please post a minimal, viable, complete example

Comment: What is the criteria for all of them to be same? Exact match?

Comment: `if 'xyz' in slots:` wont work ?

Comment: did you try `if len(slots)==len(set(slots))` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `set()` here, which will return only the unique elements in your list. If the set has fewer elements than the original list, then there was a duplicate in the original list.

```
def has_duplicate(l):
    return len(set(l)) < len(l)

has_duplicate([1,2,3,4]) # False
has_duplicate([1,2,3,4,2]) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set method to check if there is a identical element in your case.

Example:

```
import random

slotOption = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE']
slots = [random.choice(slotOption), random.choice(slotOption), random.choice(slotOption)]


if len(set(slots)) != 3:
    print("Dupe in list")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
def is_winner(l):
    #if len(set(l)) == 2 #if you want to return True on any 2 elements are the same in the list
    if len(set(l)) == 1: #if you want to return True if all elements are the same
        return 'You won!'
    else:
        return 'You lost!'
```

---

Test:

```
In [11]: is_winner(['7','7','7'])
Out[11]: 'You won!'
```